# How to render only markup in region template?

Tags: 8, blocks, theming

I have created a `region--footer.html.twig` template which only contains the static markup for the footer. Now I would like to render this region at the bottom of each page so I have added the following to the end of `page.html.twig`:

```
{{ page.footer }}
```

This works fine as long as I have connected a block to the footer region under `admin/structure/block`. If no blocks are placed in the region it is regardes as empty and is not rendered. How can I change so the `region--footer.html.twig` is used even if there is no blocks placed in the region?

I was thinking of using a preprocess function for the region doing something like this:

```
function template_preprocess_region(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['region'] == 'footer') {
    $variables['content'] = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: What purpose would it serve? I guess you can put the markup in page.html.twig and just print content in the region template.

Comment: @Kevin - I only need to display the footer region on some specific pages. I still don't understand why a region must have a connected block to be rendered, shouldn't the template for the region be parsed anyway?

Comment: It won't render if it's empty, there's no reason to do the work. Hence, the markup residing in page.html.twig instead will always output, with the region twig override just printing content. Then it wouldn't matter.

Comment: Think of it like an HTML list - it doesn't make sense to output a `<ul>` if it's not going to contain any `<li>`s, same deal with regions and blocks. Regions only exist to house blocks, so a region without blocks serves no purpose and shouldn't render. The obvious solution would be to create a block for your static footer, then you can put it in a region _and_ control visibility in the standard fashion

Comment: @Clive - I'm not sure I understand. I would like to separate the markup from `page.html.twig` by adding a specific region file with static html. The region template is not empty it conains all the markup for the actual footer - just not any connected blocks. So this can not be done - should not be done?

Comment: It can probably be done (I've never needed to so never checked how), but why do you need to? What's the benefit of putting the markup in a region rather than a block which needs no extra work/thought? I can't speak for the original authors' intentions but the fact that an empty region is not rendered by default probably suggests that you shouldn't use them as arbitrary containers, only when you need somewhere for blocks to go

Comment: I have to agree with @Clive here. You are misusing the region template. The region's purpose is to render blocks. If you don't render blocks, then don't use a region. Just put your static markup in a custom block or in your page template.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page() for page.html.twig.
 */
 function hook_preprocess_page(array &$variables) {
   $variables['page']['footer'] = [     # Specify the region name
     '#theme_wrappers' => ['region'],
     '#region' => 'footer',             # Specify the region name
     'phantom_block' => [
       '#markup' => ' ',
       '#weight' => "-100",
     ],
   ];
 }
```

This way you are adding a block with a space to the region. Forcing Drupal to render that region. But as you will put a static HTML in that region, the content of the phantom block will not be rendered.

Comment: Could you please explain how and why this should work?